# Optimal strategy for selling turnips

Tags: probability, optimization, expected-value

You have a pile of $N$ turnips that you need to get rid of in $n$ days. The turnip price every day is independently and uniformly distributed in $[0, 1]$. You can sell any amount of turnips every day, but you must sell everything by the last day. What strategy should you employ to maximize your profits?

(*Context.* This is related to the "stalk market" in *Animal Crossing: New Horizons*; see edit history.)

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842875/maximize-expected-sum-of-uniformly-chosen-numbers/3842966#3842966

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks! I've never used dynamic programming before. If we let $V(n, N, u)$ be the maximum expected profit, would we have $\displaystyle V(n, N, u) = \max_{0 \le M \le N}\left\{Mu + \int_0^1 V(n-1, N-M, t) dt\right\}$?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Rob's suggestion to use dynamic programming, I was able to work out the answer for prices following an arbitrary distribution. Here are the details.

The states are $(n, N, x)$ where

- $n$ is the number of days remaining,
- $N$ is the number of turnips you've got, and
- $x$ is the current day's price.

Let $V(n, N, x)$ be the maximum profit over all possible strategies starting from the state $(n, N, x)$. The *expected* maximum profit with $n$ days and $N$ turnips is equal to
$$W(n, N) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} V(n, N, x) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(x) \tag{1}$$
where $\mu(x)$ is the price distribution.

Now, here's the key idea. Regardless of what strategy you're following, at the end of the day you're going to sell some number $M$ of your turnips at the day's price $x$, for a profit of $Mx$, and then have $N\!-\!M$ turnips left over to sell within the next $n\!-\!1$ days, for an expected profit of at most $W(n\!-\!1, N\!-\!M)$. Therefore, the maximum profit satisfies the recurrence relation
$$V(n, N, x) = \max_{0 \leqslant M \leqslant N} \Big\{ Mx + W(n\!-\!1, N\!-\!M) \Big\}. \tag{2}$$

Although the relation (2) seems complicated, it's simplified—and, in fact, *solved*—by the observation that **$V$ is homogeneous in $N$.**

*Proof.* It's clear that $V(0, N, x) = 0$, since there are no days left to sell anything. Note that the zero function is homogeneous. So suppose by induction that for some $n$, the function $V(n, N, x)$ is homogeneous in $N$, i.e., we have $V(n, N, x) = NV(n, 1, x)$ for all $N$ and $x$. Then the function $W(n, N)$ is also homogeneous in $N$, by (1). Now, by the recurrence relation (2) and the homogeneity just established, we have
$$V(n+1, N, x) = \max_M \big\{ Mx + (N - M)W(n, 1)\big\}, $$
which is the maximum of a *linear* function in $M$ with slope $x - W(n,1)$. If the slope is positive, the function is maximized at the right endpoint $M = N$ with maximum $Nx$; if negative, it's maximized at the left endpoint $M = 0$ with maximum $NW(n,1)$. These two cases can be combined into one expression, yielding
$$V(n+1, N, x) = N \max\{x, W(n,1)\}. \tag{3}$$
Not only does (3) show that $V(n+1, N, x)$ is homogeneous in $N$ (thus completing the proof), it also **encodes the optimal strategy**: with $n+1$ days left, *sell* if $x > W(n, 1)$, otherwise *hold*.

The sequence of cutoffs $\lambda_n := W(n, 1)$ is highly dependent on the particular price distribution $\mu$. Combining (1) and (3) yields the recurrence relation
$$\lambda_{n+1} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \max\{x, \lambda_n\} \, \mathrm{d}\mu(x) \tag{4}$$
where, of course, $\lambda_0 = 0$. Specializing to the case $\mu \sim U(0, 1)$ from the OP we get $\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = 1_{[0,1]}(x) \mathrm{d}x$, so that
$$\lambda_{n+1} = \int_0^1 \max\{x, \lambda_n\} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\lambda_n^2 + 1}{2}.$$
The first few values are approximately
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\hline 
\lambda_n & 0 & 0.5 & 0.625 & 0.695 & 0.742 & 0.775 & 0.800
\end{array}
For completeness' sake, I'll also address my original intended application: the Fluctuating pattern in the *AC:NH* stalk market. There, $\mu \sim U(0.9, 1.4)$ and you have $n = 7$ chances to sell. The cutoffs are
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline 
\lambda_n & 0 & 1.15 & 1.213 & 1.248 & 1.271 & 1.288 & 1.300
\end{array}
and, following the optimal strategy, your expected profit is $W(7, N) \approx 1.31015 N$, just over a 31% return!