Optimal purchase strategy of $n$ items whose price are i.i.d uniform.
I encountered the following problem:
Let $X_1,\cdots X_n$ be i.i.d with the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}(a,b)$ and let them represent a cost of a certain item on day $n$. You need to purchase all of these items and can only purchase one a day. You may, at most $k$ times, pay the price $p$ instead of the one dictated by the distribution. What is the optimal strategy to minimize the money spent? Using this strategy, what is the average price of a single item?
In other words, each day I see the price and can decide whether I pay the market price or pay $p$ (if I still have this possibility and have not done this $k$ times already).
I am very confused by this problem. Normally when I want to find an optimal strategy, I would want to figure out price points for each day $t_1,\cdots t_n$, and if the market price is higher than $t_i$ then I pay $p$. The problem is that I somehow need to incorporate the fact that I can only do so $k$ times. So the optimal strategy should depend on the amount of days left and the amount of $k$'s left. Which really complicates the problem, and I cannot see how to approach this problem.
Some obvious observations:

If at any point you need $i$ items and you can still pay the price $p$, $i$ times. Then the optimal strategy is to simply pay $p$ or market price, whichever is cheaper.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Don’t you need two indices for your random variables? Unless I misunderstood, every object has a random price that changes every day, no?

@Aphelli I probably badly expalained the problem. There is a single item and you need to buy it $n$ times. $X_i$ represents the price on the $i$'th day of the item.

Ah, so your question is: let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be iid variables following some uniform distribution in $[a,b]$, $p \in [a,b]$ be a number and $1 \leq k \leq n$. Every day, I can choose to pay $X_i$ or $p$, but I can only choose to pay $p$ at most $k$ times – how to minimize the (expected?) total amount that I paid?

Exactly right @Aphelli.

Interesting… I’ll think it over. A first guess could be: pay $p$ while I can, when it is cheaper than $X_i$ and $X_i$ is in the interval $[b-k(b-a)/n,b]$. It’s also possible that the correct strategy varies with $k$ and $p$ – more specifically after comparing $\frac{b-p}{b-a}$ and $\frac{k}{n}$. When $\frac{k}{n}$ is greater, then the market price is “too high” and you won’t be needing it very often. When $\frac{k}{n}$ is lower, then you expect the market price to be a good deal more often than you can afford, so there may be interesting choices to make.

I think the optimal strategy is very hard to compute. I suspect I can mimic this problem : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842875/maximize-expected-sum-of-uniformly-chosen-numbers/3842966#3842966

I am going to solve this for market prices which are distributed like $\mathcal U(0,1)$. Therefore, I require $0<p<1$. The results in the case where the prices are $\mathcal U(a,b)$ can be derived from the $\mathcal U(0,1)$ result by shifting and scaling appropriately.
Let $B_{n,k}$ be the maximum market price at which you would buy the item, when you have $k$ options left and there are $n$ rounds left. We define $B_{n,0}=1$ for all $n\ge 0$; when you have no options left, you will buy even the highest price. Let $E_{n,k}$ be the expected amount you will spend on future rounds when there are $n$ rounds left and $k$ options left, assuming you play optimally. The base case is $E_{0,k}=0$ for all $k\ge 0$. We can compute $E_{n,k}$ for all $0\le k\le n$, using dynamic programming. First, we get a formula for $E_{n,k}$, by conditioning on the next market price.

If the market price is between $0$ and $B_{n,k}$, we will pay the market price this round, plus $E_{n-1,k}$ from future rounds. Conditional on the price being in the interval $(0,B_{n,k})$, its expected value is $\frac12 B_{n,k}$.

If the market price is in the interval $(B_{n,k},1)$, we will just pay $p$, plus $E_{n-1,k-1}$ in future rounds.


Therefore,
$$
E_{n,k}=B_{n,k}\cdot \left(\frac{B_{n,k}}2+E_{n-1,k}\right)+(1-B_{n,k})\cdot (p+E_{n-1,k-1})\tag1
$$
By definition, $B_{n,k}$ is the value which minimizes the RHS of $(1)$. Let $x=B_{n,k}$, so we are minimizing $\frac12{x^2}+E_{n-1,k}\,x+(1-x)(p+E_{n-1,k-1})$. Taking the derivative with respect to $x$, and setting equal to $0$, we get
$$
B_{n,k}=p+E_{n-1,k-1}-E_{n-1,k}.\tag2
$$
Now, if you substitute $(2)$ into $(1)$, then $(1)$ becomes a formula for $E_{n,k}$ in terms of $E_{n-1,k}$ and $E_{n-1,k-1}$. Therefore, when making a table containing the value $E_{n,k}$ in the $n^\text{th}$ row and $k^\text{th}$ column $0\le k\le n$, then you can fill out the $n^\text{th}$ row using the values from the $(n-1)^\text{st}$ row. You will have to use the fact that $E_{n,n+1}=E_n$, because when $n$ rounds are left, at most $n$ options are useful.
